# Does Wine 1.3.X have a PPA for Natty

Tags: 11.04, wine, ppa

Upon upgrading from Maverick to Natty (development) it broke the Wine PPA. Deleting it and adding it again (though it says Natty in it's address) is broken. Update manager moans about not being able to get all packages etc.

Comment: If you mean the ubuntu-wine ppa, I can't find natty in the distribution list (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I keep getting weird errors from launchpad when I try and copy the Maverick packages to Natty for the PPA:

> The following source cannot be copied:
>
> wine1.3 1.3.11-0ubuntu1 in maverick (same version already has published binaries in the destination archive)

I have no idea what this error means but apparently it doesn't mean there are binaries in the destination archive.

So, until I (or Launchpad) fixes this, no Natty Wine packages.

UPDATE: I am now doing binary copies (not rebuilds) of the maverick packages to Natty.  This should work until Natty gets multiarch (which it may not), then I'll have to do a proper fork.

UPDATE: as of now the Wine PPA for Natty works just fine.  I will discontinue it when Natty becomes unsupported, and possibly earlier if there's another compelling reason.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no ppa for wine for Ubuntu Natty yet. Did you try to purge ubuntu-wine ppa and then try to add it again(wine ppa for maverick)? what about wine version in official Ubuntu repository?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to be there (there is "natty" dir in http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu).

But I still use Maverick Wine 1.3 PPA (because there was no for Natty when I've started using it) with Natty (Xubuntu 11.04) and everything works at least as fine as default 1.2 does.

Just add

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main

or

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu maverick main

to your /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: At the moment, the Natty packages are binary copies of the Maverick ones, so either one won't matter.  But for forward compatibility do the "proper" natty thing because eventually the packages will need to diverge.